# How to create Vite based Vue component library consumable via .mjs files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I created a Vite based Vue library. This library should distribute a single component inside a .mjs file.

---

**Library setup**

I basically created a new Vue app via `npm create vue`, moved every dependency to dev dependencies and added this to the package.json

```
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/computedRenderer.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/computedRenderer.umd.cjs"
    }
  },
```

After that I added the following to my vite.config.ts file

```
  build: {
    lib: {
      name: "mylib",
      fileName: "computedRenderer",
      entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/myComp/index.ts'), // index file exporting my component
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

Building the project should generate you a computedRenderer.mjs in the dist directory ( as expected ).

---

**File server for testing purposes**

I created a small Node server serving the static .mjs file

```
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";

const port = 3_000;

express()
    .use(express.json())
    .use(cors())
    .use(express.static('./public')) // directory contains the generated .mjs file
    .listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    });
```

When running the server and calling

> http://localhost:3000/computedRenderer.mjs

you should get the file content

---

**How I consume the component**

In my main project I try to import the component dynamically during runtime like so

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from "vue";

onMounted(async () => {
  const source = 'http://localhost:3000/computedRenderer.mjs'; // example url
  const { ComputedRenderer } = await import(source);

  // ...
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately I get the following warning

> The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite. See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.

and error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Is my library setup wrong? Or how can I consume the component via url?

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: please share your mjs file

Comment: You listed `vue` as `external` so it is not bundled. You are using ESM from a browser context so the loader needs more info on where to find the bare specifier `'vue'`. You should try import maps. That's only one of your issues...

Comment: Did you even read the limitations imposed by rollup when using dynamic imports? You cannot specify a variable only as your import.